# How to make Rails use images/fonts contained in Yarn packages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

In migrating an app to Rails 5.1 for the first time, I'm experimenting with yarn instead of bower to manage frontend dependencies.

Everything is working great, and I'm able to include `js` and `css` files via the relevant `application.js/css` manifest files.

But, if these files depend on other resources (e.g., a directory of images, fonts, etc.), then Rails knows nothing about them.

Given a yarn package that includes:

```
/css
  |-styles.css
/images
  |-background.jpg
```

where

```
#styles.css
.background {
  background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
}
```

Logs are (obviously) showing

```
No route matches [GET] "/images/background.jpg"
```

How do I ensure that Rails is aware of these images in Yarn packages and properly compiles them?

Is this possible? Or am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: you mean, images located in app/assets/images ?

Comment: thanks @Ben. No, that is the problem. The images are part of the Yarn package (`node_modules/my_package/images`), and hence Rails does not know about them. I could manually copy to `/assets` to solve this. But is there a better way?

Comment: I see; I will double check, but as you can in other environments while running react or similars with webpack, you might be able to call ./{your_package}/path/to/image.jpg, as a "symlink" to node_modules is made available

Comment: First you need to import your image :
```
import "../images/background.jpg"
```

Comment: thanks @Snake, yes that's logical. But where and how does one import images? I don't think in the css manifest?

Comment: @AndyHarvey Do you have any idea ? I have same problem with third lib. Does it mean I must copy the image of thirdpart lib in public folder ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am wondering the same thing.

Comment: Same problem here... how can I use an image file (in CSS) located in yarn package?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Following are some good references

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html#using-webpacker-for-css

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/349

Basically you need to do following things

1. Require the css file like a js file but with css extension included in `/app/javascript/packs/application.js` (Yes, require css in javascript)
2. Add `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag "application" %>`  in layout file if already not there
3. If you don't already have it, create file (even if empty) `/app/javascript/packs/application.scss`